# Azure IoT SDK C Set up a macOS (Mac OS X) development environment

Tags: c++, c, azure, azure-iot-sdk

Pulled down the [MXCHIP basic example for Azure IoT Central](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/tree/master/MXCHIP/mxchip_basic) as is and get this error.

```
sketch/src/iotc/sdk_plat/iotc.cpp:14:53: fatal error: azure_prov_client/prov_security_factory.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure I need to [Set up a macOS (Mac OS X) development environment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/devbox_setup.md#macos), but I'm getting stuck at the [Building the C SDK with CMake directly](http://Building%20the%20C%20SDK%20with%20CMake%20directly) step. I use cmake to build the SDK and then what? Even after completing this setup I am stilling getting this missing library error.

Comment: You might want to use Azure IoT Workbench extension for VS Code https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/get-started/#install-development-environment

Comment: I did this and installed all of the Azure IoT realted SDKs in the Arduino IDE and was able to make some progress. Details here.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this following this thread on [Required SDKs for Arduino IDE](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/issues/46).

New issue discovered compiling the Arduino sketch gave me an "[undeclared functions prov_dev_set_symmetric_key_info and hsm_client_set_registration_name_and_key](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/issues/48%20Undeclared%20functions%20prov_dev_set_symmetric_key_info%20and%20hsm_client_set_registration_name_and_key)" error. Click to link for this new error for progress on resolution.